# How to add @keyframes rule through inspect element?

Tags: css, keyframe, web-inspector, inspect-element

I constantly like to customize web pages that I use frequently through inspect element to be more pleasing for me, however, I've been constantly failing at adding a @keyframes rule to css. Everytime I click "New Style Rule" and type my code, it simply disappears.

```
  0%{
    text-shadow: 0 0px 15px #f0f;
  }
  33%{
    text-shadow:0 0px 15px #0ff;
  }
  66%{
    text-shadow: 0 0px 10px #0f0;
  }
  100%{
    text-shadow: 0 0px 10px #ff0;
  }
}
```

I have noticed in other websites that use keyframes that they are separated from regular classes, and I cannot interact in any way with it through inspect element.
     [@keyframe in inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHFyy.png)

Is it impossible to add keyframes through inspect element alone?

Answer (score 1):

there are some chrome extensions that helps with page css editing, like [amino](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amino-live-css-editor/pbcpfbcibpcbfbmddogfhcijfpboeaaf/related?hl=en-GB).

alternatively, you may handle the css file directly at `Sources` tab.

At `Sources` tab you have all content files served including css files. the css files will be in purple. most likely it's compressed, but you can pretty print with `{}` button in the bottom left. once there, you can edit it anyway you like it, do your tests, and see translated to the page layout.